# How to modify this Javascript to work without any html code?

Tags: javascript, html

I found a Javascript code that records sound in the browser. It consists of an HTML code and a Javascript code and that's my problem because I only want a Javascript code without HTML code.
How can I convert this code to pure Javascript to use in **Storyline**?
In **Storyline**, I have two buttons named "**Start**" And "**Stop**" to execute Javascript just like the code below.

**How Can I get rid of that HTML code and still do sound recording?**

HTML Code:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>Audio record and playback</h2>
        <p>
            <button id=startRecord>start</button>
            <button id=stopRecord disabled>stop</button>
        </p>    
        <p>
            <audio id=recordedAudio></audio>
            <a id=audioDownload></a>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript code:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true})
.then(stream => {
    rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    rec.ondataavailable = e => {
        audioChunks.push(e.data);
        if (rec.state == "inactive"){
            let blob = new Blob(audioChunks,{type:'audio/x-mpeg-3'});
            recordedAudio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            recordedAudio.controls=true;
            recordedAudio.autoplay=true;
            audioDownload.href = recordedAudio.src;
            audioDownload.download = 'mp3';
            audioDownload.innerHTML = 'download';
        }
    }
})
.catch(e=>console.log(e));

startRecord.onclick = e => {
    startRecord.disabled = true;
    stopRecord.disabled=false;
    audioChunks = [];
    rec.start();
}

stopRecord.onclick = e => {
    startRecord.disabled = false;
    stopRecord.disabled=true;
    rec.stop();
}
```

Here is the link :

https://jsfiddle.net/sasivarunan/bv55z5fe/

Comment: In the end you will always always and always need HTML in the browser. There are some frameworks out there with which you have a virtual dom and you create elements in the style the framework intends it for you but the moment the website is loaded you will have HTML. Pure JavaScript is not possible. So your buttons need to be written in HTML or search for one of the tons of frameworks which give you alternative ways to declare buttons and other components.

Comment: @JonathanStellwag you can also create DOM elements in javascript....

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here. I use an E-learning authoring tool named Storyline, I create those buttons with it. I just need to find a syntax to convert this line of HTML code to javascript : <audio id=recordedAudio></audio>

Comment: Alright. That makes more sense. So you try to write some kind of generator for every HTML element. The answer posted is they way you need to go then. But let's say it like the following: what you try to achieve is to write your own layer between the JavaScript and the DOM. So I detail the amount of work will be the same like you write a framework. Nevertheless it's an ok question. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your javascript create the DOM elements so that your solution requires zero modified HTML, although it seems like a rather obtuse requirement:

```
;(function() {
  let audioChunks = []

  const startRecord = document.getElementById('startRecord')
  const stopRecord = document.getElementById('stopRecord')
  startRecord.addEventListener('click', () => {
    startRecord.disabled = true
    stopRecord.disabled = false
    audioChunks = []
    rec.start()
  })

  stopRecord.addEventListener('click', () => {
    startRecord.disabled = false
    stopRecord.disabled = true
    rec.stop()
  })

  const recordedAudio = document.createElement('audio')
  document.body.appendChild(audio)

  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    .then(stream => {
      rec = new MediaRecorder(stream)
      rec.ondataavailable = e => {
        audioChunks.push(e.data)
        if (rec.state == "inactive") {
          let blob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: "audio/x-mpeg-3" })
          recordedAudio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
          recordedAudio.controls = true
          recordedAudio.autoplay = true
          audioDownload.href = recordedAudio.src
          audioDownload.download = "mp3"
          audioDownload.innerHTML = "download"
        }
      }
    })
    .catch(e => console.log(e))
})()
```